# Relative reacting tendency of H2/Pd towards double bond and triple bond in straight carbon chain

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, hydrogen, catalysis, hydrocarbons

> If both double bond and triple bond is present in a straight carbon
>   chain the which one (double bond or triple bond) will be reduced by
>   $1$ equivalent of $\ce{H2(Pd)}$ ?

My guess is that the triple bond should react as it is more reactive but I'm not sure. Also does the answer depend on whether the double bond and triple bond are conjugated with each other or not?

Let us consider two examples (A) and (B):

(A)

[image]

(B)

[image]

Which bond will be reduced in case (A) and (B) ?

Comment: March *Advanced Organic Chemistry* 7th ed, p 1499 lists alkynes as being easier to reduce than alkenes (in general), although I guess it will probably depend on the exact substrate.

Comment: @orthocresol Thanks. Does it depend on whether the double bond and triple bond are conjugated or not? Any ideas?

Comment: Triple bond will be more reactive because it can be adsorbed easily on the surface of catalyst through its pi bonds. If double and triple bonds are in congugation then also triple bond is more reactive as in this situation product formed will be conjugated diene.